# Были ли изменения в папке за определённый период?

Tags: git, git-log, git-diff

В файловой системе проект разбит на папки.

Как узнать, были ли изменения в папке за определённый период?

Как это сделать в программе TreeSource?

Comment: Не знаю как в TreeSource, но если использовать Tortoise Git, то в контекстном меню есть пункт show log - там можно посмотреть всю историю репозитория, в том числе отфильтровать по времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что за программа TreeSource -  не знаю. А все хорошие вещи git делаются в консоли. Итак, вот команда, которая скорее всего сделает все, что нужно

```
git diff --name-only master@{"10 day ago"} master -- папка/подпапка/
```

разбор по кускам.

```
--name-only - выводить только имена
master@{"10 day ago"} - с какого периода и ветки брать. Здесь есть разные варианты.
можно sha хешем указать.
master - в данном случае это просто текущее состояние. Но можно и здесь указать период. (пример ниже).
-- (два дефиса) - это признак того, что параметры закончились.
папка/подпапка/ - собственно, где смотреть в проекте
```

Ещё один пример.

```
git diff --name-only master@{"10 day ago"} master@{"5 day ago"} -- папка/подпапка/
```

выбрать изменения за период 10-5 дней назад.

или так

```
git diff --name-only master@{"1 week ago"} master@{"yesterday"} -- папка/
```

или даже так

```
git diff --name-only master@{"Wed Feb 16 14:00 2013 +0100"} master@{"yesterday"}
```

Comment: Спасибо.
[TreeSource](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) это git менеджер от Attlasian. Делают они эту тулзу, чтобы поддерживать заказчиков для Jira. которые используют git хранилища на [bitbucket.org](http://www.bitbucket.org/)